# Static analysis: sound vs unsound

Tags: static-analysis

I have started working with static analysis. After reading few papers, one thing remains unclear to me. What are correct definitions of sound and unsound static analysis?

Problem is that I find contradictory definitions in different places:
"...sound analysis models all behaviors of a program." http://blog.errstr.com/2013/01/17/on-static-analysis/

"Unsound tools/Formal tools: These tools report all defects checked for & produces no false negatives."
http://techvolve.blogspot.de/2014/03/static-analysis-overview.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definitions in http://techvolve.blogspot.de/2014/03/static-analysis-overview.html are reversed. It should be:

- Unsound tools: These tools sacrifice maximization of finding bugs to minimizing false positives to a reasonable level. So, these tools are intentionally imprecise & undecidable - this means possible false positives & false negatives.
- Sound tools/Formal tools: These tools report all defects checked for & produces no false negatives. These are relatively slower. but, produces a large amount of false positives.

That page is not particularly well-writen even if you omit the mix-up. The word “undecidable” is still used in a non-conventional sense in the first paragraph. (A *problem* is either decidable or undecidable. A tool is neither one nor the other.)

You had better omit this article from your bibliographic search.

Comment: This article is not the only with definition mistake. Some papers, published on conferences (they are in minority compered to those which state "...sound analysis models all behaviors of a program."), that I have read contain the same definition. I first ignored them, but once I reached this article, suspicion rose. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @xTrmwYs another issue that you may have encountered in articles is a different convention for what is being detected. In static analysis, we detect bugs, which gives their meaning to “false positives”, “false negatives” and “sound”. Apparently in other sub-domains of computer science they detect correct programs, so the meanings of “sound” and “complete” are reversed for them.